# Concatenate a folder's Java files, with a header for each file

Tags: shell, cat

I have an obligation to provide a document which just contains every source code file, with the file's name before each file.

Example:

```
=============================
src/com/example/Factory.java
=============================

public class Factory {
...
}

=============================
src/com/example/Worker.java
=============================

public class Worker {
...
}
```

It must contain all *.java files in the current folder, recursively.

How to easily generate such a file, using commonly available commands or a small script?

Answer (score 2):

First write a small script called `print-with-header.sh` with the content below, and make it executable:

```
echo ""
echo "=================================================================="
echo $1
echo "=================================================================="
echo ""
cat $1
```

Then run:

```
find . -name "*.java" | xargs -L 1 ./print-with-header.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the appearance of the header, here's a quick way. First run `set -o globstar` in ksh93 or `shopt -s extglob` in bash (or nothing in zsh). Then:

```
tail -n +1 **/*.java
```

If you'd like something nicer for printing, you can use programs such as [a2ps](http://www.gnu.org/software/a2ps/) or [enscript](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/).

Comment: Nice! The header appears like this: `==> src/com/example/Factory.java <==`